# How to implement a batch start for Azure table service using REST API for .Net 2 C#

Tags: c#, .net, rest, azure

I'm stuck using .Net 2.0 for an app needing storage in Asure.

I can write records fine enough using http POST methods using the REST APIs and JSON but want/need to batch inserts for performance reasons.

I've read MSDN the documentation about using the rest API to batch here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd894038.aspx

I cannot seem to figure out how to get the batch started. The samples listed don't make sense to me. It looks like the first POST en each example is not quite right. Some weird double header thing going on with two boundaries and mime types.

Is there a clear example of how to start the batch using the REST API or even how to do the batch in general with the REST API?

Again, we are using .Net 2 so don't have access to the new AZURE objects.

Cheers!

TJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listings show nested multipart HTTP requests with a set of changesets nested within a batch. Each part in the changeset, delimited by `--changeset_<some_guid>`, is an operation on the table represented as a HTTP message.

Each part in the changeset first contains a header describing the content type of the part followed by a second the header for the HTTP message and its body. I'm assuming this is what you meant by the "weird double header thing."

The [implementation of the batch operation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/ebca01bfb75c66af5a9f3b2fa70c115dc157e4dd/Lib/WindowsRuntime/Table/Protocol/TableOperationHttpRequestFactory.cs#L94-L159) from the .NET Azure Storage SDK uses the OData client libraries which requires [.NET 4 and up](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.OData/5.6.4). So you might have to write your own implementation unless you can find an implementation targeting .NET 2. Alternatively, deploy another service running on a supported version of .NET framework to proxy writes table storage.

Regarding examples, the section on [batch requests](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc406398359) in the OData spec details the requests. It's probably also worth noting that table storage has some additional constraints in the requests as described in the first two sections in the MSDN article you linked to.